# Как правильно установить dropzone programmatically?

Tags: php, javascript, yii

```
<div id="dropZed" class="dropzone"></div>

     js скрипт в самом конце файла
   <script>
       var dzone = new Dropzone("#dropZed", {
          paramName: "img_url",
          url: "/admin/MyGallery/create",
          method: "files"
       });
       Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
     </script>

   php обработчик
   if(isset($_POST['submit'])){          - нажатая кнопка
        print_r($_FILES['img_url']);
    }
```

Когда жму отправить выходит ошибка index: img_url ERROR 500. Ошибка понятно нету img_url. Начал смотреть в firebug, когда я только сую картинку в этот квадрат dropzone идет FILES запрос а когда жму сабмит идет запрос POST. Использую виджет CActiveForm иза этого выбрал programmaticall. Как исправить эту проблему ?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте переместить `Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;` до блока инициализации.

Comment: нет не помогло  Dropzone.autoDiscover = false; здесь кажется даже не причем

Comment: Тогда попробуйте указать `method: "post"`. Потому что метод может быть либо `post`, либо `put`, либо функция.

Comment: Вообще, все у вас выглядит правильно, вроде бы... Сам часто пользуюсь этой библиотекой и проблем не возникало. Правда, я использую Питон на сервере. Обратите внимание, что в ошибке фигурирует `img_url` - это не связано с `paramName`?

Comment: я и FILES и POST и GET писал, все ровно не помогает. а на счет img_url да он связан с paramName я его по идет должен в котроллере словить $_POST['img_url']

Comment: Словить должны в $_POST['img_url'] или все-таки $_FILES['img_url']?

Comment: if(isset($_FILES['img_url'])){
            if($_FILES['img_url']['error'] == 0){
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img_url']['tmp_name'],
                Yii::app()->request->baseUrl . 'images/upload/' . $_FILES['img_url']['name']);
            }}                    Мне $_FILES над но если этот код можно переделать под $_POST можно и пост

Comment: Если вы указываете метод `post` и при этом в `$_POST` пусто, то это очень странно...

Comment: когда я только сую картинку в этот квадрат dropzone идет запрос FILES а когда жду кнопку отправить идет запрос POST.

Comment: В руководстве написано, что по умолчанию идет запрос POST, кстати, а в кнсоли js какие-то ошибки появляются?

Comment: да не все чисто, мне так кажется когда я тока сую картинку он уже делает запрос $_FILES а потом когда жму сабмит идет другой запрос $_POST

Comment: Дело в том, что dz начинает отправлять файлы автоматически, как только они попадают в зону, за это отвечает флаг `autoProcessQueue`, так что нажатие на сабмит, по идее, никак не должно влиять на работу формы.

Comment: что посетуете ? как быть тогда ?

Comment: Попробуйте установить `autoProcessQueue: false` и вручную вызвать `dzone.processQueue()` и посмотрите, что из этого получится.

Comment: И посмотрите раздел реализации серверной части http://www.dropzonejs.com/#server-side-implementation там есть пара туториалов для php.

Comment: нет нет чёто не получается(, блин как у других получается а у меня нет.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте воспользоваться готовым composer пакетом https://github.com/yanpapayan/yii-dropzone или расширением http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-dropzone (там в комментариях есть примеры и похожие вопросы).

А использовать напрямую $_POST или $_FILES нежелательно - лучше использовать `Yii::app()->request->getPost()` например

Comment: но у меня с английским не все ок, не могли бы подсказать что эти строки делают $options = CMap::mergeArray(array(
                'url' => $this->url,
                'parallelUploads' => 1,
                'paramName' => $this->name,
                'accept' => "js:function(file, done){if(jQuery.inArray(file.type,{$this->mimeTypes}) == -1 ){done('File type not allowed.');}else{done();}}",
                'init' => "js:function(){this.on('success',$this->onSuccess);}"
                ), $this->options);
ошибка выходит Не определено свойство MyGalleryController.url.